# Active Directory get all user's logon hours(when they're allowed to log in) using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

Is it possible to get all the AD user's logon hours and output it into an excel spreadsheet. So something like:

| Name | Logon Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 9am-6pm |
| Jane | 8am-5pm |
| Chris | 9am-6pm |

So far I have Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties LogonHours | ft Name, LogonHours. However the output is all in binary.

Comment: Active Directory doesn't store this info by default. You have to turn it on, and even then it's not stored in AD, but in the event log.

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood what you were asking. The AD `logonHours` field is not a record of when the user has logged in, but a policy indicating when they are allowed to log in.

Comment: Sorry about that should have made it clearer.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is explain here : [Understanding the AD Account attributes - LastLogon, LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogonDate](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx)

Comment: `logonHours` is [stored as 21 bytes, 3 bytes per day, each covering 8 hours](https://nettools.net/how-to-decode-logonhours-attribute/) - you'll have to inspect the individual bits, and then calculate ranges across on all contiguous segments

Comment: LogonHours should be a 21 byte array, with each set of 3 bytes representing one day of the week. `[convert]::ToString($byte,2)` should convert each byte to something like `10001111`, with the three bytes together comprising the 24 hours of each day, and a 1 indicating that they are allowed access during that hour, and a 0 indicating that they are not.

Answer (score 1):

> However the output is all in binary.

That happens to be the way AD stores it. The `logonHours` attribute value consists of 21 bytes, each byte covering an 8-hour window, starting from midnight **on Sunday**.

As [TheMadTechnician notes, converting the byte values to binary/base-2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485294/active-directory-get-all-users-logon-hourswhen-theyre-allowed-to-log-in-usin#comment122817033_69485294) might be the simplest way of accessing each "hour".

With this in mind, we could make a nifty little helper class that can translate the byte array into meaningful logon hour information:

```
class LogonHourAdapter
{
  hidden
  [string[]]$_days

  LogonHourAdapter([byte[]]$logonHours)
  {
    if($logonHours.Count -ne 21){
      throw [System.ArgumentException]::new('logonHours', "Expected byte array of length 21.")
    }
    $this._days = [string[]]::new(7)
    for($i = 0; $i -lt 7; $i++){
      $offset = $i * 3
      $this._days[$i] = ($logonHours[$offset..($offset+2)]|ForEach-Object{[convert]::ToString($_,2).PadLeft(8, '0')})-join''
    }
  }

  [bool]
  IsAllowedToLogonDuring([DayOfWeek]$day, [int]$hour)
  {
    if($hour -ge 24){
      throw [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException]::new('hour')
    }

    return $this._days[$day][$hour] -eq '1'
  }

  [int[]]
  GetLogonHoursOn([DayOfWeek]$day){
    $hours = 0..23 |? {$this._days[$day][$_] -eq '1'}
    return $hours -as [int[]]
  }
}
```

Now we don't need to worry about parsing the binary data, we just pass the attribute value to an instance of the class:

```
PS ~> $bob = Get-ADUser Bob -Properties logonHours
PS ~> $bobHours = [LogonHourAdapter]::new($bob.logonHours)
PS ~> $bobHours.IsAllowedToLogonDuring('Monday', 9) # Bob is allowed to logon after 9am
True
PS ~> $bobHours.IsAllowedToLogonDuring('Monday', 6) # But not earlier!
False
```

Next, we'll want to track "ranges" - contiguous periods throughout each day where the user is allowed to logon.

For each day, simply "walk" through each hour from 0 through 23 and start tracking a new range everytime there's a break:

```
# Prepare our logon hour adapter
$lha = [LogonHourAdapter]::new($bob.logonHours)

# Extract ranges for each day of the week
$ranges = foreach($day in -split 'Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday'){
  $currRange = $null
  0..23|%{
    if($lha.IsAllowedToLogonDuring($day, $_)){
      if(-not $currRange){
        $currRange = [pscustomobject]@{ Day = [DayOfWeek]$day; From = $_; To = $null}
      }
      $currRange.To = $_ + 1
    }else{
      if($currRange){
        $currRange
        $currRange = $null
      }
    }
  }
  if($currRange){
    $currRange
  }
}
```

Now we just need to group them together so we can express "8-16 (Monday, Tuesday, Friday)" instead of "8-16 (Monday), 8-16 (Tuesday), 8-16 (Wednesday) ... etc.":

```
$label = $ranges |Group-Object From,To |Sort Count -Descending |ForEach-Object {
  '{0:00}-{1:00} ({2})' -f $_.Group[0].From,$_.Group[0].To,(($_.Group.Day |Sort) -join', ')
}
```

And `$label` now contains a more human readable version of Bob's logonHours:

```
PS ~> $label
08-16 (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday)
```